# How do I create a rails association for cypress testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cypress

I am trying to test a form on one particular page on my web app. The problem is that this web page depends on at least three model objects to be in the database for various reasons that I'll elaborate and since I'm new to Cypress for the testing, I'm not exactly sure how to go about this. So here are the problem areas:

```
 describe('Basic SSL Certificate', () => {
  context('csr submission', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      cy.request('POST', 'user_session/user_login', { login: 'testuser', password: 'Testing_ssl+1'})
        .as('currentUser')
      cy.appFactories([
        ['create', 'certificate_order']
      ]).as('certificateOrder')
    })

    it('rejects a numerical ip address for its csr', () => {
     cy.visit(`/team/${this.certificateOrder.ssl_account.ssl_slug}/certificateOrders/${this.certificate_order.ref}/edit`);
```

First of all, the problem I am facing is this simple line of test code here:

```
cy.visit(`/team/${this.certificateOrder.ssl_account.ssl_slug}/certificateOrders/${this.certificate_order.ref}/edit`);
```

I need to hit the following url which looks like this `/teams/abcd-xyz/certificate_orders/co-ref-1234/edit`

Questions: How do I create rails associations with cypress? In my before block, I think I created a certificate order, does that have the associations with it on creation? Do I have to create each model seperately with `appFactories` and if I do, how do I "link" them together?

I don't see the way to combine ruby and javascript in this code and could use a pointer on setting up the factories. Usually in rspec I would create the models that I need and use them but in cypress I'm not sure how to do this because it doesn't seem to be the right way of doing it with JS. Helpful advice would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways you can setup associations:

- Setting the foreign keys
- Using transient attributes
- Using Nested Attributes

I have examples of all 3 in this post: https://medium.com/nexl-engineering/setting-up-associations-with-cypress-on-rails-and-factorybot-3d681315946f

My preferred way is using transient attributes as it makes is very readable from within Cypress

Example:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :author do
    name { 'Taylor' }
  end

  factory :post do
    transient do
      author_name { 'Taylor' }
    end
    title { 'Cypress on Rails is Awesome' }
    author { create(:author, name: author_name ) }
  end
end
```

Then in Cypress you can do the following:

```
// example with overriding the defaults
cy.appFactories([['create', 'post', { title: 'Cypress is cool', author_name: 'James' }]]

// example without overriding
cy.appFactories([['create', 'post']]
```